# Redirecting each user to different page

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I am creating a photography website for a friend. Part of it is a Client Login area where clients can enter the username and password my friend has given them to view all the photos from their shoot/ wedding etc.

I have created the client login form and login.php:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

$clientdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$user' and     password='$pass'")
     or die (mysql_error());


$data = mysql_fetch_array($clientdata, MYSQL_ASSOC);


if(mysql_num_rows($clientdata) == 1){

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;

    $username = $hook->getValue('username');

    $pageId = 'index';

    switch ($username) {
      case 'Marie&Peter':
              $pageId = 'MarieWeddingGallery.php';
              break;
    }

$landingPage = $modx->makeUrl($pageId, "", "", 'full');
$modx->sendRedirect($landingPage);

}else{header('Location: clientLogin.html');}
```

The switch part is supposed to redirect the user based on the username they gave, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can just add one more field to your database: i.e. targetPage.
instead of using switch in PHP. and then do a simple redirect on the same row of recordset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to fully answer this question we will need to know what $modx is. It appears the problem lies in $modx->makeUrl() or $modx->sendRedirect().

A quick solution is to replace the line

```
$pageId = 'MarieWeddingGallery.php';
```

with

```
header('Location: MarieWeddingGallery.php');
```

This is the same technique you're using to redirect to the login page.

Finally, using a switch to load pages based on user name is not a good way to do this. Every new user will require you to add code to support them. You should add a field to your database for the gallery page. Other techniques could be used as well.

To load the page based on a database field you should replace the switch with

```
header('Location: ' . $data['targetPage']);
```

This expects the targetPage field in the database to contain the full name of the php file (e.g. 'MarieWeddingGallery.php').

Comment: @MichaelMitch I have added the field to my database. Sorry I'm quite new to this as you can probably guess by my messy code! What code would I need to add to redirect to the file listed in the database? I named the field 'targetPage' like suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you get $username from $hook? You already have username in variable $user.

```
switch ($user) {
```

should solve your problem.